# Search Complexity of a Hashtable within a Hashtable?

Tags: hashtable, time-complexity

Say we have a hashtable of size m, and at each bucket we store a hashtable of size p.
What would the worst case/average case search complexity be?

I am inclined to say that since computing a hash function is still atomic, the only worst case scenario is if the value is at the end of the linked list in the hashtable of size p, so O(n)?

I have no idea how to calculate the average case for this scenario and would appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's still linear in the worst case, if conflicts are resolved by adding to a linked list. A two-level hashtable with `n` slots at the first level and `p` at the second is identical to a single-level hashtable with `np` slots. All elements you add could end up at the same second level slot, all be added to the same linked list, etc. Based on this observation, the average-case complexity is the same as that of a single-level hashtable with `np` slots that uses linked lists to resolve collisions.